# The Calculation Process

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand HOW the calculation is done to retrieve the value 9, -6 and 18?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Notice that the grey bar in the first matrix is horizontal and each bar in the second matrix is vertical.  The first entry in the product matrix is $ \ 1 \cdot 2 \ + \ 3 \cdot 3 \ $ , the second is $ \ 1 \cdot 0 \ + \ 3 \cdot (-2) \ $ , and the third is $ \ 1 \cdot (-4) \ + \ 3 \cdot 6 \ $ .  The entries in the second row of the product matrix would then be  $ \ 2 \cdot 2 \ + \ (-1) \cdot 3 \ $ , $ \ 2 \cdot 0 \ + \ (-1) \cdot (-2) \ $ , and $ \ 2 \cdot (-4) \ + \ (-1) \cdot 6 \ $ .  (continued)

Comment: The first entry in the horizontal bar is multiplied by the top entry in the vertical bar, then added to the second entry in the horizontal bar multiplied by the bottom entry in the vertical bar.  This continues for each vertical bar.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the dot product of two vectors?

Comment: "" dot product"? I don't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}\color{maroon}{1} & \color{maroon}{3}\\ \color{blue}{2}& \color{blue}{{-1}}\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}\color{red}{2} & \color{green}{0} & \color{fuchsia}{{-4}}\\ \color{red}{3}& \color{green}{{-2}} & \color{fuchsia}{6}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\color{maroon}{1}\cdot\color{red}{2}+\color{maroon}{3}\cdot\color{red}{3} & \color{maroon}{1}\cdot\color{green}{0}+\color{maroon}{3}\cdot\color{green}{({-2})} & \color{maroon}{1}\cdot\color{fuchsia}{({-4})}+\color{maroon}{3}\cdot\color{fuchsia}{6}\\ \color{blue}{2}\cdot \color{red}{2} + \color{blue}{({-1})}\cdot\color{red}{3} & \color{blue}{2}\cdot\color{green}{0} + \color{blue}{({-1})}\cdot\color{green}{({-2})} & \color{blue}{2}\cdot\color{fuchsia}{({-4})}+\color{blue}{({-1})}\cdot\color{fuchsia}{6}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2+9 & 0-6 & {-4}+18\\ 4-3 & 0+2 & {-8}-6\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Does this help you visualise it?

In general when computing the product of two matrices you should look at the following: the **row vectors** of the first matrix and the **column vectors** of the second matrix. Each element in the resulting matrix is computed by taking the product of the first elements, then add the product of the second elements, etc.